# SQL Query - Mathematical Query across 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, math, join, multiplication

I think the Title is a bit off what I need, so if someone thinks of a better title please don't hesitate to change it.

My issue is this: I have a TIMESHEET table, and a RATES table.

The TIMESHEET table looks like this:

```
|RATE-ID|OT |DAY1|DAY2|DAY3|DAY4|DAY5|DAY6|DAY7|DAY8|DAY9|DAY10|DAY11|DAY12|DAY13|DAY14|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1   |1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 0  | 0  | 7  | 8  |  1  |  2  |  0  |  5  |  6  |
|   5   |1.5| 6  | 5  | 4  | 3  | 2  | 0  | 0  | 1  | 0  |  7  |  6  |  4  |  3  |  2  |
```

The RATES table looks like this:

```
|ID|  RATE  |
|1 |  50.00 |
|2 |  30.00 |
    ....
|5 |  100.00|
```

So then what I do in terms of a query (once off, so no worries about SQL injections) is this:

```
SELECT sum(DAY1)+sum(DAY2)+sum(DAY3)+sum(DAY4)+sum(DAY5)+sum(DAY6)+sum(DAY7)+sum(DAY8)+sum(DAY9)+sum(DAY10)+sum(DAY11)+sum(DAY12)+sum(DAY13)+sum(DAY14) as TOTALHOURS, OT, RATES.RATE from TIMESHEET INNER JOIN RATES on TIMESHEETS.RATE-ID = RATES.ID
```

Works fantastic - 3 seperate columns that tell me the total hours, the OT multiplier, and the rate. Now comes the part I'm struggling with. I can't seem to multiply the TOTALHOURS column against anything. I can do the simple `OT * RATE as NEWRATE` and get it down to 2 columns: TOTALHOURS and NEWRATE.

My question is, how do I multiply these two dynamically named columns to get the result?

i.e the first one would be 49 (sum of line 1) * 1 (OT for line 1) * 50 (Rate for line 1) = 2450

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Dee.

Comment: Off the top of my head, use sub queries to achieve these type of things, or temporary tables.

Comment: You can put your query to an CTE, and then calculate the result

Comment: @Grigor I am only just entering the SQL world, so I'll get onto reading about sub-queries and temporary tables. Thanks!

Comment: @cha Thanks for that. I'll have a look at the common table expressions and get back to you about it. Thanks again!

Comment: You can also do this: `select (sum(day1)+sum(day2)+....)*OT*RATES.RATE AS Total FROM...`

Comment: BTW, it looks like you are missing `GROUP BY` clause. Does your query actually work?

Comment: Haha, that worked perfectly @cha. Exactly what I was after. Saved me doing the math manually for over 1000 rows! Thanks for that! If you'd like to add that as an answer I'll accept it; but if you could also make reference to CTE's so that people who have this issue can learn about them that'd be great. - still reading about subqueries, temporary tables and CTE's.

Comment: Yes I've omitted some data for the sake of security, changed the table names, etc.

Comment: At the end of the query I have my `group by RATE-ID, RATE, OT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a single line query without the hassles of running subqueries, temp tables, CTE's, group by clauses, or what have you, just try cleaning up the query a bit like this:

```
SELECT sum((DAY1+DAY2+DAY3+DAY4+DAY5+DAY6+DAY7+DAY8+DAY9+DAY10+DAY11+DAY12+DAY13+DAY14) * RATE * OT) as TOTALL FROM from TIMESHEET INNER JOIN RATES on TIMESHEETS.RATE-ID = RATES.ID
```

SQL has a wide variety of ways to accomplish the same result. Try the different ones and find the type that suits you and the application well.

Comment: @DeeKayy90 though this might do what you want it to do, I would highly recommend you to learn proper way of doing these types of things. Temp tables, sub queries,  etc... Cheers!

Comment: @Grigor I most definitely will do! Is there any specific resources you know off the top of your head that will assist me in making better queries? Thanks!

Comment: Google is your friend, @DeeKayy90.  I personally gained most of my SQL knowledge from my job.  It's hard to come up with 'scenarios' and write SQL for them.  Now, I've interviewed many people that have claimed 'SQL knowledge of 8/10' (which most probably was from online tutorials) but have demonstrated 3-4/10 knowledge.  No matter what resources you digest, you won't cover 'everything'.  If you keep using SQL, the skill will come.Happy coding!

Comment: Hehe, that's how I am learning. That and I have a couple of colleagues who have been in the field much longer that I pester for their knowledge! I'll continue Googling away though. There's an abundant amount of information out there. Thanks again for all your help @Grigor, it is greatly appreciated.